# Adding Cluster Admin rights in Windows Server 2012

Tags: permissions, cluster-computing

I've been troubleshooting an issue all day on a windows server 2012 cluster.  2 nodes sit in 1 data centre, and a third node sits in a separate data centre.  The WSFC underlies a SQL Availability group configuration which is what I have been troubleshooting today, but have traced the issue to a need to set registerallproviderids to 0 on the cluster.

Unfortunately I can't as I am being told I do not have administrative privileges on the cluster.  Exact error is:

"Get-ClusterResource:  You do not have administrative privileges on the cluster.  Contact your network administrator to request access.  Access is denied"

Which is pretty clear.  However I am a domain administrator, a local administrator on every node of the cluster.  I tried to explicitely add my login to the administrators role via cluster manager and I get the message:

"Access to the cluster can be granted/denied only to domain users and groups.  Please use the security tab to remove the local users or groups."

I assume this is coming from existing users as the account I am adding is definitely a domain account.  The administrators listed are:
SYSTEM
NETWORK SERVICE
SQL service account on one of the nodes(node 2 oddly enough)
Local Administrators(Also on node 2)
MSDTC
and 2 accounts which are SID's like "S-1-5-21......"

Has anyone seen this before or can give me any idea of how to work around this?  This is a live cluster, so I can't take it offline or recreate it.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a way to make this work.  The clue was in the local administrator and the service account being specific to node 2.  While I still couldn't add myself to the administrator group on node 2, because I was in the local admin group if I logged into that node I was treated as an administrator and was able to change the cluster settings.

Answer (score 0):

In our environment we have all users flagged as Protected Users which disables NTLM and forces Kerberos. The error was due to that. As soon as I removed my account from being a protected user it worked to add the new node.